# Why do some apps which work from command prompt dont run from powershell?

Tags: command-line, powershell, application-launch

Taking an example of a exe called nimble.

I can access this program through command prompt without issues.
However when I try to type `nimble` in powershell, it gives me

```
PS C:\Users\risharan\DevSpace\Nim\ng2base> nimble
Program 'nimble' failed to run: No application is associated with the specified file for this operationAt line:1 char:1
 + nimble
 + ~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
 + nimble
 + ~~~~~~
 + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
 +
```

I would have assumed that if command line has access to any env variable, powershell will have that too.

Comment: Does it run with `& nimble` in Powershell? And is it _really_ an `.exe` file?

Comment: I can run it if i give the path to the exe. I cant run it as & nimble. nimble.exe is in a bin folder. this folder is already in my path env variable.

This is something I have seen for a lot of other stuff as well. some of the exe's which are in my path variable are not directly accessible from powershell.

Comment: You need to do `& "Full\Path\To\Exe"`. It won't work without the full path, I think

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Whatever you can run via CMD, should run the same in PS if you use `cmd /c $commandstring`, where `$commandstring` = what you would do in the cmd prompt